# Using <Alt>+l for any custom shortcut in ubuntu 16.04 triggers a text entry window

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

I did not have this problem before, assigning `<Alt>+l` for non-custom shortcuts works normally.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't it be *Alt+l*

Comment: Yeah,  I meant Alt+l.

Comment: [Edit] it then.